# Prevent an entry in model from adding itself in many2many relationship

Tags: django-models, m2m

I want to prevent a user from following themselves in Django. The User model is defined like bellow:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(‘self’, related_name=“following”, symmetrical= False)
```

Changing `save()` method in the User model doesn’t help since `add()` method doesn’t call `save()`. The seems to be a solution using `m2m_changed` or `UniqueConstraint` but I don’t know how to implement them. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UniqueConstraint` will not help since this will only enforce that you do not follow the same user twice.

What you can do is construct a [**`through=…`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), and enforce that the follower and the followee are not the same:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Q

class User(AbstractUser):
    # …
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        related_name='following',
        symmetrical=False,
        through='Follow',
        through_fields=('followee', 'follower'),
    )
```

In the `Follow` model we then enforce that `follower` and `followee` can not be the same:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    followee = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='followee_set'
    )
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='following_set'
    )

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.follower_id == self.followee_id:
            raise ValidationError('Can not follow self.')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['follower', 'followee'], name='follow_once'),
            models.CheckConstraint(check=~Q(follower=F('followee')), name='not_follow_self')
        ]
```

Not all databases however *enforce* the `CheckConstraint`. Therefore it might be better to implement a `clean` method as well.

Comment: After adding your code and run makemigrations and migrate again, the error `OperationalError: no such table: network_follow` keep showing up.

Comment: Migrations for 'network':
  network\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model User
    - Create model Post
    - Create model Follow
    - Add field followers to user
    - Add field groups to user
    - Add field user_permissions to user
    - Create constraint follow_once on model follow
    - Create constraint not_follow_self on model follow

Comment: @NguyễnThếQuý: did you run the migrations on the database?

Comment: You mean `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` ?

Comment: Migrations and migrate does't rise any error, it only happens when I use `objects.add()` method

Comment: @NguyễnThếQuý: but the error indicates it did not construct the `Follow` model. Can you construct the migrations and tables from scratch, that will likely be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: needed to construct the table again to make it work